# Apple M2 Macbook Pro Segmentation Fault using uWSGI and requests library

Tags: python-requests, segmentation-fault, uwsgi, apple-m1

I have a project with the following set-up and I'm encountering a Segmentation Fault. Has someone encountered this or something similar and was able to fix it?

Computer: Apple Macbook Pro M2

Pyenv, python, version 3.10.5,
openssl@1.1,
Django==4.1.1,
requests==2.28.1,
uwsgi==2.0.20,

uswgi ini file:

```
processes = 1
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
http = 127.0.0.1:8080
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081
master = true
python-auto-reload = 1
thunder-lock = true
max-requests = 5000
harakiri = 1200
buffer-size = 65535
disable-logging = true
```

If I change `master` into `false`, then there isn't any segmentation fault anymore. The segmentation fault is triggered when the `requests` library makes any type of request, so I am imagining that the issue is either with uwsgi, the requests library, or openssl

Segfault message reads:

```
!!! uWSGI process 94052 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 94052 ***
0   uwsgi                               0x0000000100c89398 uwsgi_backtrace + 52
1   uwsgi                               0x0000000100c898ac uwsgi_segfault + 56
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001b04b42a4 _sigtramp + 56
3   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00000001b022e098 _os_log_preferences_refresh + 36
4   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00000001b022eae0 os_log_type_enabled + 644
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b05199c8 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 204
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b05198dc -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 52
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b0519890 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b0511f44 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 376
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b068c734 -[_CFXPreferences withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 384
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b0511818 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 168
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b0511734 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 112
12  SystemConfiguration                 0x00000001b10e08cc SCDynamicStoreCopyProxiesWithOptions + 180
13  _scproxy.cpython-310-darwin.so      0x000000010215b85c get_proxy_settings + 44
14  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001011ca2ec cfunction_vectorcall_NOARGS + 332
15  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
16  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101262204 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25452
17  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
18  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
19  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101262204 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25452
20  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
21  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
22  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101262204 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25452
23  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
24  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
25  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010126227c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25572
26  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
27  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
28  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010126227c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25572
29  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
30  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
31  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101262154 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25276
32  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
33  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001011846e8 method_vectorcall + 168
34  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101182430 PyVectorcall_Call + 144
35  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001012624a4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26124
36  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
37  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101182430 PyVectorcall_Call + 144
38  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001012624a4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26124
39  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
40  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
41  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010126227c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25572
42  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
43  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001011846e8 method_vectorcall + 168
44  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
45  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010126227c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25572
46  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
47  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001011846e8 method_vectorcall + 168
48  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
49  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010126227c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25572
50  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
51  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101182430 PyVectorcall_Call + 144
52  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001012624a4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26124
53  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
54  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101182430 PyVectorcall_Call + 144
55  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001012624a4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26124
56  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
57  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101182430 PyVectorcall_Call + 144
58  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x00000001012624a4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26124
59  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
60  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
61  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101262204 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25452
62  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x000000010125bd8c _PyEval_Vector + 164
63  libpython3.10.dylib                 0x0000000101264b9c call_function + 316
*** end of backtrace ***
```

Comment: My first guess would be that openssl native C code has an incompatible binary, and then it crashes when Python tries to call this code.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/857094

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce. What does the application code do? Does it spawn any worker threads at startup?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to upgrade the requests library to the latest version, which might resolve the issue if it is due to a bug in the library. You could also try to configure the requests library to use a specific proxy, rather than relying on the system's proxy settings, which may bypass the issue with the SystemConfiguration library.

Additionally, you could try to isolate the issue by disabling the uwsgi configuration option master = true and run the application with a single worker process. This would help you to determine if the problem is with uwsgi or with the requests library.